# React Bootstrap: preserve current tab on page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

The question has been asked many times before, but never for React Bootstrap: how do you preserve the active tab on page reload? In other words, when a user clicks a tab in the navbar, it is easy to add a hash to the current page URL. However, when the page is reloaded, the `eventKey` is not consistent with the URL. I've scoured the following RB docs and haven't found a prop intended for this purpose:

- https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#tabs
- https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tab-container-props

Here is my code:

```
<Card className="m-auto w-100 w-xl-75">
  <Tab.Container id="tabs">
    <Card.Header>
      <Nav variant="tabs">
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link href="#licenses" style={{ outline: 'none' }}>Licenses</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link href="#releases" style={{ outline: 'none' }}>Releases</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
    </Card.Header>
    <Card.Body>
      <Tab.Content>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey="licenses" id="licenses">
          <Licenses licenses={licenses} />
        </Tab.Pane>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey="releases" id="releases">
          <Releases releases={releases} />
        </Tab.Pane>
      </Tab.Content>
    </Card.Body>
  </Tab.Container>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not pretty sure if I understand your question, but given the context, I would suggest that you store the user's currently selected tab in one of the caches, sessions of the frontend.

For example,

By using session storage:

You could store your selected key on the following way:

```js
const storeSelection = (selection) => localStorage.setItem('tabSelection', selection);
```

```html
<Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link href="#licenses" style={{ outline: 'none' }} onSelect={{this.storeSelection('licenses')}}>Licenses</Nav.Link>
</Nav.Item>
```

Then, you can just select that tab `onComponentDidMount` or just any other place you prefer.

I'm assuming that this state that you want to store is more of a state that you want to keep on the frontend side.